# How often can you auto post with new open graph?

Tags: post, facebook-opengraph

My company is creating a game and we plan to use the new open graph features to post to users timeline when performing certain actions within the game.

The question is, how often can you auto post? We plan to do it a lot when achievements are earned, levels are passed, etc. We are asking for permissions and displaying what will be posted in the permission box. Can we post to timeline as much as we want? I can't find any regulations for the new auto posts on facebook.

Answer (score 1):

You should post any valid user action in your game. Facebook will manage throttling, and distribution to Timeline, Ticker and Newsfeed.

You can't post actions which a user didn't actually take in your game.

Achievements are different. Theres a quota of 1000 points per user per game - these must be spread across your achievements so you can't grant more than the quota per user - see the achievements docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/

The normal limits of 600 api requests in 600 seconds per access token still apply.